# List plot with vertical lines between corresponding data points

Tags: plotting

Given two lists

```
list1 =
  {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.707107}, {3, 0.866025}, {4, 1.}, {5, 1.11803}, {6, 1.22474}, 
   {7, 1.32288}, {8, 1.41421}, {9, 1.5}, {10, 1.58114}};
list2 = 
  {{1, 0.85}, {2, 1.20208}, {3, 1.47224}, {4, 1.7}, {5, 1.90066}, {6, 2.08207}, 
   {7, 2.24889}, {8, 2.40416}, {9, 2.55}, {10, 2.68794}};
```

of xy data pairs which correspond in their x-values, how can I make a plot showing the points in the two lists with vertical lines between them? It should look like:

[image]

Comment: Try `ListPlot[{list1, list2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`.