# ListPointPlot3D filling between two lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm trying to connect pairs of corresponding points from two lists in a ListPointPlot3D (similar to what was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162462/list-plot-with-vertical-lines-between-corresponding-data-points?noredirect=1&lq=1) but in 3D).  `Filling-> {1->{2}}` isn't working for me, so I presume the problem must lie in how I'm passing the two lists.

```
SeedRandom[11];
sigma = DiagonalMatrix[{0.001, 0.001, 0.000001}];
sp = 5;
means1 = Flatten /@ 
   Transpose[{Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2], {sp}], Table[0.8, {sp}]}];
dist1 = MixtureDistribution[Table[1, {sp}],
   Table[MultinormalDistribution[means1[[i]], sigma], {i, 
     Table[j, {j, sp}]}]
   ];
means2 = Flatten /@ 
   Transpose[{Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2], {sp}], Table[0.2, {sp}]}];
dist2 = MixtureDistribution[Table[1, {sp}],
   Table[MultinormalDistribution[means2[[i]], sigma], {i, 
     Table[j, {j, sp}]}]
   ];
n = 50;
data1 = RandomVariate[dist1, n];
data2 = RandomVariate[dist2, n];
ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Comment: Almost! What I'd like to for each point in the top layer to be connected to only one point in the bottom layer.  Which point is connected to which is determined by their position (order) in the data (i.e. first point in data1 connects to first point in data2).  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might be useful for others to see my mistake:

```
SeedRandom[11];
sp = 4;
maxVar = 0.02;
means = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2], {sp}];
dist = MixtureDistribution[Table[1, {sp}],
   Table[BinormalDistribution[means[[i]], 
     RandomReal[{0.01, maxVar}, 2], 0.5], {i, Table[j, {j, sp}]}]
   ];
n = 50;
pos = RandomVariate[dist, n];
data1 = Flatten /@ Transpose[{pos, Table[0.8, {n}]}];
data2 = Flatten /@ Transpose[{pos, Table[0.2, {n}]}];

Show[ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"data1", "data2"}], 
 Graphics3D[{Gray, Line@Transpose[{data1, data2}]}]]
```